# Data Cleaning in Python for Topic modelling

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am novice in python. I have a column as below in a dataframe (df2)

[image: Input]

i want to introduce a column which will be as follows

[image]

Can someone please help me

Comment: can you post the output of `df.head(10).to_dict()`?

Comment: 1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: nan,
  9: nan},
 'Unnamed: 999': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: nan,
  9: nan},
 ...}

Comment: pls post full output in your question so the other can reproduce your dataframe.....bcz of formating it is hard to understand the structure of dataframe

Comment: i just need a new column which should have all the data of the what the customer is saying frm the comments column

Answer (score 2):

```
#dataframe used by me:
df=pd.DataFrame({'Record': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 2},
 'Comments': {0: 'Agent: abcded',
  1: 'Customer: dffg',
  2: 'Customer: ok',
  3: 'Agent: will talk through',
  4: 'Agent: Welcome',
  5: 'Customer: Help Needed',
  6: 'Agent: State Emergency',
  7: 'Customer: Intrusion at my door',
  8: 'Customer: Help me asap'}})
```

try:

```
df=df.reset_index()
c=df['Comments'].str.contains('Customer')  
#checking if Customer is present in the column Comments
df['New Column']=None   #creating New Column
```

Finally:

```
df.loc[c,'New Column']=df.loc[c,'Comments'].str.split(':',1).str[1]    
#Changing The Value of New Column Where Condition 'c' satisfies
```

Now If You print `df` you will get your desired output

If needed then use:

```
df['New Column']=df.groupby('Record')['New Column'].agg(sorted,key=pd.isnull).explode().values
```

Comment: The output is like this |Record||Comments |
-----------
|1| |abcded|
    |Customer: dffg|
    |Customer: ok|
    |Agent: will talk through|
---------------------------
|2| |Welcome|
    |Customer: Help Needed|
    |Agent: State Emergency|
    |Customer: Intrusion at my door|
    |Customer: Help me asap|
---------------------------------

Comment: i.e. the first line of Agent:abcded is replaced with abcded the rest is the same no change

Comment: @Krishnamurthy can't understand because of the formatting...Updated answer see the dataframe from which I tested this

Comment: @Krishnamurthy Sir It's working on my sample dataframe...If your dataframe has different structure(which doesn't seem after seeing pic) then I don't Know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233844/discussion-between-krishnamurthy-and-anurag-dabas).